# How to auto initialize a list with increasing numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, list, initialization

I want a new list to be initialized

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
```

with a increasing number e.g.

if the list has 10 elements they have to be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
List<int> l = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

The classic way, using a for-loop:

```
List<int> l = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    l.Add(i);
```

or using LINQ (hiding the loop from you):

```
List<int> l = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
```